# VBA Copying from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy information from one workbook to another existing workbook, but the wrong information is being added.

```
Sub Set_Open_ExistingWorkbook()
Dim UserRoleWkb As Workbook, ConfigWkb As Workbook, UserRoleWkst As Worksheet, ConfigWkst As Worksheet
Set UserRoleWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cs\Desktop\Ar.xlsx")
**Set ConfigWkb = ActiveWorkbook**
Set UserRoleWkst = UserRoleWkb.Sheets("RS Users")
**Set ConfigWkst = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet**

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 10 'user role
For i = 8 To 16 'config
    If ConfigWkst.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
       UserRoleWkst.Cells(j, 2).Value = ConfigWkst.Cells(i, 2).Value
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The part of the code with the ** around it is the issue. When I call the ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheeet, it is grabbing the information from the UserRoleWkst (worksheet) rather than what I wanted: Configwkst.

I have tried this but will get errors on the ConfigWkst line and the code will not run:

```
    Sub Set_Open_ExistingWorkbook()
Dim UserRoleWkb As Workbook, ConfigWkb As Workbook, UserRoleWkst As Worksheet, ConfigWkst As Worksheet
Set UserRoleWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cs\Desktop\Ar.xlsx")
**Set ConfigWkb = ActiveWorkbook**
Set UserRoleWkst = UserRoleWkb.Sheets("RS Users")
**Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.Sheets("Users")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 10 'user role
For i = 8 To 16 'config
    If ConfigWkst.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
       UserRoleWkst.Cells(j, 2).Value = ConfigWkst.Cells(i, 2).Value
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open another workbook then that will become the ActiveWorkbook, so you need to get that reference before opening UserRoleWkb

```
Set ConfigWkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.ActiveSheet

Set UserRoleWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cs\Desktop\Ar.xlsx")
Set UserRoleWkst = UserRoleWkb.Sheets("RS Users")
```